# Node.js beaten C# in TCP Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, tcp

I'm writting TCP Server for a game in C# with TPL. I came across on Node.js on the internet and it seems that it has much better performance and is generally better for server than .Net.
Is that true?

PS. I have to say I hate JS's scripting convention, and I would be relieved if you said my C# server concept is not in danger

Comment: take a look [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/202234/is-it-a-right-thing-to-do-to-use-node-js-as-a-tcp-server) is the best answer that i've found for you

Answer (score 2):

node.js will sometimes be faster than c#. and only sometimes *much* faster. for a game server it might be a good choice. c# will be faster in some cases too however.

you might just continue your c# work.

understanding the difference between event based server and a threading server (TPL is still threading, although it schedules them considering machine cores) you might be able to estimate if node.js is faster in your case. if you did not yet, read http://nodejs.org/about/ for example.

if you want to *know* which one is faster you will have to implement both and measure.

as cool as node.js is - i always preferred single threaded solutions and often argue(d) against thread fanatics - do not believe the overhype that everything non-node.js is bad and that node.js is always the "much fastest". understanding the architecture difference is a dev must have, so dig into it.

Comment: may the downvoting child write 20 times "i shall not downvote just because i'm mad".